# Elliptic equations with divergence-free drift terms

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

Given
$\
\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla c=\Delta c-a_{1}c+\rho \text{ on }\Omega $ with a $\Omega \subset 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{2}$ bounded, $div$$(\mathbf{u})=0$, $\mathbf{u\in L}^{2},$ and $\rho
\in L^{2}$. $\ $and boundary Dirichlet conditions (or Neumann conditions!).
What can I say about the existence of solutions and regularity results for this equation?
(Gilbarg and Trudinger's book doesn't have an answer for this kind of
problem because they ask for $\mathbf{u\in L}^{\infty }$ in the hypotheses).
I would appreciate very much some precise references for this problem.

Comment: When $u$ is divergence free one can obtain good estimates on a solution $c$ even when there are essentially no regularity assumptions on $u$.    Check my account because I asked a very similar question a while ago...